# angular-chart custom tooltip position not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi guys I am wondering how can I fix the tooltip position on hover a point, I have checked many related posts in stackoverflow, also I've tried all these examples on my implementation:

```
https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/tree/master/samples/tooltips
```

But the position still no working, this is the plunker with my issue:

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/KJEpxR0oCJcYIrd1KJU0?p=preview
```

Answer (score 1):

In the file script.js, change the lines 63 and 64 with these:

```
tooltipEl.style.left = position.left + tooltip.x + 'px';
tooltipEl.style.top = position.top + tooltip.y + 'px';
```

Image:
[image]
<sub>(source: [imgsafe.org](https://i.imgsafe.org/65d255f1ad.png))</sub>

Comment: yeah, it almost fixed, but now the tooltip stay at the bottom of the page, on hover with the mouse, I appreciate your help Ali

Comment: Actually with that fix, the tooltip is located between the two related points which look fine I believe. 
![Valid XHTML](https://i.imgsafe.org/65d255f1ad.png).

Comment: Ali Tahouri you are right, the position looks better now, the problem is when trying this fix on my app, [link](http://prntscr.com/db8h7c) the tooltips is at a very top position of the mouse, but thx for your help any way

Comment: Thanks Erick, is the tooltip, that red rectangle inside the pie chart? or is it the one at very top of screen?
If that's the one in the very top, then I guess the x, y values are passed as 0 for some reason, but I need more details in the real code to figure out what's the actual issue.

Comment: haha it is the one at the very top of the screen, the red square over the pie chart is the place where I mouse over. well I guess Im going to create another plunker with a pie chart, using a layout as the picture that I've sent to you

Comment: Cool, I think that would help a lot to figure out what's happening.